# How to fix - Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, dart

When building my Flutter project, I am getting the following error. How should I fix this?

> C:/src/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart.exe --enable-asserts D:\Apps\Flutter\roster_me_on\lib\main.dart
> lib/pages/forgot_password.dart:27:20: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'WidgetsBinding' which excludes null.

`WidgetsBinding` is from `package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart`

full path : `/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart`

The code that the error points to is the `WidgetsBinding.instance!` line.

```
class _ForgotPasswordState extends State<ForgotPassword> {
  StreamController<bool>? _events;

  bool _displayMessage = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _events = new StreamController<bool>();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => doRequest(context: context));
  }
```

Comment: probably you are using a plugin/package that is not fully supported for the new flutter version. The warning appeared after the release of flutter version 3.x.x

Comment: WidgetsBinding.instance is no longer nullable, so the null-check isn't needed.  This is new in Flutter 3.0, which has been around for a while now.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning, explaining to you that `WidgetsBinding` can't be null and you don't need the ! there. If you remove it, the warning will disappear